# How to tell which nfsd thread serves which client? nfsd/client mapping

Tags: linux, nfs

Is there a way to see which nfsd thread serves which client? Does such a mapping even exist or is a client request randomly distributed among idle nfsd threads?

Comment: You may want to poke around in /proc/<pid> for one of the nfsd threads and see what you can find.  If there's any sort of mapping, the information would likely be stored in there somewhere.  We don't use nfs where I'm at, so I can't look around much, but that'd be where I'd start.

Comment: @Fubar I searched with grep for the clients hostnames but couldn't find something in there. A search for the IP adresses shows all cients in `/proc/<PID>/task/<PID>/net/arp`, `/proc/<PID>/net/arp` and `/proc/<PID>/net/rpc/auth.unix.ip/content` but nothing with regards to only one of the clients.

Comment: well... I wouldn't use hostnames to grep on... the system doesn't care much about what you call the systems.  Try the IP addresses, but even that may not work.  It's likely if the IPs were there they would be converted to a hex number.  You can use something like http://www.networkers-online.com/tools/ip-hex-converter to convert the IP to a hex string, then search on that.  The files I've seen storing that contain that info, such as /proc/net/nfsfs/servers, use all lowercase for the hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work, but you might try something like `lsof -n | grep nfsd` and check the output.

Comment: This only shows `/proc/<PID>/exe` and `/` for each `nfsd` plus `/proc/<PID>/net/rpc/nfsd.export/channel` and `/proc/<PID>/net/rpc/nfsd.fh/channel` for `rpc.mount`.